# Is there a working alternative for mysql on Sierra (10.12.6) that can be used with php?

Tags: macos, mysql, php, database

Does mariadb function properly on Sierra? I can't get mysql to work and since Sierra isn't supported by mysql I'm giving up on trying to get it to function.   does anyone have Sierra working as a functional web development server because I am just trying to test an ecommerce website. I don't need it to do much.  what database just works I don't care if its free or not

Comment: What problems are you having with mySQL on Sierra? Obviously the latest versions might not work on Sierra, but that's the same with everything else, it's an old OS, and support has been dropped. But mySQL CS 8.0.12 did support Sierra, even though the release was primarily targeted for High Sierra.

Comment: I can't get past the socket error:  Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)    Ive tried every suggestion I've found online nothing is working.   I can't find any logs with the word mysql in it so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Which version of the server did you install? If you tried multiple, did you completely uninstall one before installing another?

Comment: I installed multiple versions, I am not sure if I completely uninstalled every one of them, for example when I used the native package installer, and used the uninstall feature on the preference pane including the option to also delete the preference pane and launchd files,  I assumed that would uninstall everything.  yet with the next native installation package version I attempted to install, it had "upgrade" next to the preference pane and launchd files which to me indicates that they existed somewhere still somehow

Comment: I currently have it installed and running via homebrew. but I can't get past that socket error.   and I don't know why cause all the solutions seemed to work for others with this problem.  changing the permissions hasn't helped.. Its in the my.cnf file  though no clue if I have that in the right spot or not..  its in /etc/ and I copied it to /etc/mysql/ because it didn't exist there and someone said it usually would

Comment: If you're willing to give mySQL another go, try completely uninstalling it — in addition to the uninstall option in the prefpane, make sure there is no `/usr/local/mysql*`, no startup items `/Library/StartupItems/MySQL*`. Check if you have a `/private/etc/hostconfig` file, if you do, you need to go through it as well. Also delete the installation receipts in `/Library/Receipts/` and `/private/var/db/receipts/` that have mysql in the name. The case sensitivity will be tricky, mysql, MySQL, MYSQL, delete them all. Speaking of which, what is the filesystem you are using? Is it case sensitive?

Comment: Ugh, I don't know if mixing the homebrew version and installer package from oracle was a good idea. I assume you are going to use the Community Server edition, if/when you try again, stick to the Oracle installer, version 8.0.12 for Sierra from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392505/does-anyone-have-mysql-working-on-sierra for the MySQL question

Comment: Why even go through this trouble?  I highly  doubt your ecommerce site is running on macOS.  Virtualize a *nix box, install your AMP stack for development and you never have to deal with  any of the issues you’re experiencing now.